# Pitfalls of SQL database table BULK update, using staging table and bulkcopy in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I have been on the quest to improve speed of a table update in my vb.net program.
 The scenario is that I have a table with 10,000 rows and 160 columns.
 This table is updated very frequently with 1 to 100+ column changes per row.
 Using `DataAdapter` update is very slow and unsuitable and has been investigated without improved results.

The next option is most likely the process of dumping the data in to a staging table using `bulkcopy`, deleting all rows from the original database table and then issuing a copy command to move the data from the staging table back to the original table I wish to update.

The difference in speed is staggering considering the update process takes place 30-50 times during programs execution of a data run

Dataadapter update = 10-15s multiplied by 50 = 12.5 MINUTES

Bulk update as described = 1.2-1.4s multiplied by 50 = 1.16 Minutes

Extraordinary difference! So I really want to take the bulk update option.
I understand that it is not conventional but this table will remain at 10,000 rows, and the program is single thread single user local database eliminating a lot of the potential problems.

My main concern is data safety.
I have the code already enclosed in a try-catch, but maybe there is a way to ensure that all processes run correctly that involves SQL transaction like they do in a bank, so if something goes wrong everything is reversed.
Given that my skill level does not extend past creating the code below.
**What is the best possible implementation of the procedure ?**

```
 Try

            ESTP = "Start Bulk DBselection Update"

            Dim oMainQueryT = "Truncate Table DBSelectionsSTAGE"
            Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
                Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(oMainQueryT, con)
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using

            ESTP = "Step 1 Bulk DBselection Update"

            Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(RacingConStr)
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBSelectionsSTAGE"
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DBSelectionsDS.Tables("DBSelectionsDetails"))
                bulkCopy.Close()
            End Using

            ESTP = "Step 2 Bulk DBselection Update"

            oMainQueryT = "Truncate Table DBSelections"
            Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
                Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(oMainQueryT, con)
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using

            ESTP = "Step 3 Bulk DBselection Update"

            oMainQueryT = "Insert INTO DBSelections Select * FROM DBSelectionsSTAGE"
            Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
                Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(oMainQueryT, con)
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using

            Data_Base.TextBox25.Text = "Deleting data - DONE "
            Data_Base.TextBox25.Refresh()

DBSelectionsDS.Tables("DBSelectionsDetails").AcceptChanges()

        Catch ex As Exception

            ErrMess = "ERROR - occured at " & ESTP & " " & ex.ToString
            Call WriteError()
            Call ViewError()

        End Try
```

Edit: I incorporated the code into my project and adopted the changes suggested by Dan.
The 'update' now takes less then a second. That is a vast improvement on the previous code. Im not sure how well this scales, but in my situation where the table remains roughly the same size (number of rows) Im very happy with the outcome.

Dont forget to accept changes on the datatable when done`DBSelectionsDS.Tables("DBSelectionsDetails").AcceptChanges()`

Comment: If you're using ADO.NET like you are, then why not use the `SqlTransaction` class? See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10223/Using-Transactions-in-ADO-NET. Transactions are built in to .NET

Comment: And http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111109-1.aspx is also relevant

Comment: adaam, thank you for those very informative links, they together explain what I need to do perfectly !

Comment: Something truly weird is going on, because 10000 rows is _tiny_ comparatively speaking.  Even if you updated every rows and every column, it should not take more than a minute if that much.  Can you share the nature of the updates?  Have you considered not using a DataAdapter and just use simple ADO.Net coding using SqlCommand object?

Comment: Chris, the time stated is the TOTAL time, when the process runs there is between 30 to 50 updates. Each takes about 15 seconds to complete. But when you add it all up it makes a difference. I must confess it is due to poorly written code, that I did many years ago, when I just started. With no time to rewrite the procedure, I am forced to apply a fix such as the one above which will go a long way towards improving the situation. And Im learning new things. So Im very grateful for the help that I have received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing steps 2 and 3 with a transactional `TRUNCATE` and `SWITCH` to replace the contents of the `DBSelection` table with the staged data.  SWITCH is much more efficient than copying the individual rows because it is a meta-data only operation.

`SWITCH` is commonly used in SQL Server Enterprise Edition to move (not copy) data to/from partitioned tables but it can also be used with non-partitioned tables and in lesser editions. The basic requirements for SWITCH are that the source and target tables have identical schema (including indexes), reside on the same filegroups, and the target empty.  The source staging table will be empty after the operation.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx for more details about `SWITCH`.

Below is an example of how you could implement this technique.

```
Try

    ESTP = "Start Bulk DBselection Update"

    Dim oMainQueryT = "Truncate Table DBSelectionsSTAGE"
    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(oMainQueryT, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

    ESTP = "Step 1 Bulk DBselection Update"

    Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(RacingConStr)
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "DBSelectionsSTAGE"
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DBSelectionsDS.Tables("DBSelectionsDetails"))
        bulkCopy.Close()
    End Using

    ESTP = "Step 2 and 3 - replace DBselection with staged data"

    oMainQueryT = _
        "SET XACT_ABORT ON;" + _
        "BEGIN TRAN;" + _
        "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DBSelections;" + _
        "ALTER TABLE dbo.DBSelectionsSTAGE SWITCH TO dbo.DBSelections;" + _
        "COMMIT;"
    Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(RacingConStr)
        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(oMainQueryT, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

    Data_Base.TextBox25.Text = "Replaced data - DONE "
    Data_Base.TextBox25.Refresh()

Catch ex As Exception

    ErrMess = "ERROR - occured at " & ESTP & " " & ex.ToString
    Call WriteError()
    Call ViewError()

End Try
```

Comment: So the truncate stage table is not needed, as the bulk update is the only operation that uses it? Could I place step 1 and steps 2-3 in the same transaction ? would that keep the data safe? Safer ? I don't want  some incident where I end up with no data in the table, but that would only ever happen if the bulk copy failed and the switch somehow executed regardless of the success  of the bulkcopy. The 2 database tables are identical, and the data table in the application is also, so any issues with data come up before the update procedure. SO a transaction would be as safe as it gets ?

Comment: or is the try catch enough to deal with any bulkcopy issues,? As I notice that you have already included a transaction on the switch operation.

Comment: @user1500403, the `TRUNCATE` of the staging table isn't needed befor the bulk copy as long as the happy path is followed.  I suggest you keep it just in case something goes awry since the bulk copy is in a separate (implicit) transaction.  The process will then be re-runnable.

Comment: @user1500403, although you could instead wrap it all in a System.Transaction but then the transaction manager/coordinator needs to get involved due to the different connections.  That is less efficient, which I understand is your primary concern.  Also, I think it is unlikely the unhappy path will kick in with your safeguards but the multi-statement transaction un the code I posted will guarantee safety.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is completely valid. If you needs rollback the information, you must use a log transaction statement not Bulk copy.

So, I suggest create a STORED PROCEDURE inside SQL-SERVER and add INSERT and UPDATE for control transaction.

Additionally you can use SET NOCOUNT ON inside the SP (in the first line), you can have a little surprise in your performance.